# How to work with multiple Google accounts at one time instead of manually editing

Tags: google-analytics, web-analytics

I am in charge of several Google Analytics accounts and basically, I'm just looking for a systematic way of working with multiple accounts at once instead of making manual edits. For example, I created a new filter and I need to add it to a bunch of accounts. Instead of doing that manually for all of them I would like to have a way to do it for all of them at once.

I know this is possible with Analytics API but that would require me to actually learn the API and program some functionality which I have no time for right now. I  need an existing solution.

My research led me to [Analytics Edge](http://www.analyticsedge.com) and [Analytics Canvas](http://www.analyticscanvas.com) and not much else. Are there any other tools for editing multiple Google accounts?

Comment: If you had asked about how to use the Analytics API, I'm sure many people would have been happy to assist you, but what you're asking is off topic here.

Comment: There is a stackexchange site dedicated to software recommendations, I think it would be much more appropriate to ask there if you want a tool (however you might overestimate the difficulties in using the API, so if you want advice on that I'll be happy to help).

Comment: Perhaps you mean underestimating? If I'm using a third-party tool like the ones mentioned I figured it would be pretty easy but how difficult would you say it is?